# Getting the new questions in the ios StackExchange app

Tags: support, ios-app

Once the tag has been selected for a particular site in the ios app, looks the questions are sorted by popularity. How can the questions be sorted by date to see all the unanswered questions at the top?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have chosen a tag and gone to its page to see its questions, there should be a type in area at the top.

Immediately to the right of that is a button that looks like a pair of up and down arrows.

Pressing that should allow you to choose Newest.

If you are not on the page that I have anticipated, and do not see that button, then pull down the top of the screen and it will probably be revealed.

Comment: Thnx - It was not intuitive from the screen - there should be an option to make it default option